# How to get the value from an EditText as you start typing?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to display the text that the user enters in an EditText in a TextView.

As the user starts typing, the value of the TextView should change.

eg: If the user types *a* the value of the TextView should be changed to *a* and then he types *b* after that, the value of the TextView  should be changed to *ab*...

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>

<EditText 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/editText"/>
```

This is the xml I'm using.

So is there anything like a **edittext.setOnTypeListener** so that I can add the textView's text directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a text change listener for this purpose.
Do it like this.

```
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    yourTextView.setText(s.toString());
  });
```

You may use it according to your convenience in the before,after or onTextChanged method.